# Inserting a one-line line comment with a preprocessor macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to simulate a one-line comment (`//`) using a preprocessor macro (or magic)? For example, can this compile with `gcc -std=c99`?

```
#define LINE_COMMENT() ???

int main() {
    LINE_COMMENT()  asd(*&#@)($*?><?><":}{)(@
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible or useful.

Comment: In C, selectively commenting out sections of code is done with `#if`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Here is an extract from the standard showing the phases of translation of a C program:

> 3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. Each comment is replaced by one space character. New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.
> 4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and `_Pragma` unary operator expressions are executed. If a character sequence that matches the syntax of a universal character name is produced by token concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is undefined. A `#include` preprocessing directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1 through phase 4, recursively. All preprocessing directives are then deleted.

As you can see, comments are removed *before* macros are expanded, so a macro cannot expand into a comment.

You can obviously define a macro that takes an argument and expands to nothing, but it's slightly more restrictive than a comment, as its argument must consist only of valid preprocessor token characters (e.g. no `@` or unmatched quotes). Not very useful for general commenting purposes.

Comment: A macro argument cannot include unmatched quotes or unmatched parentheses. But there is no problem with @; it is a valid preprocessing-token, but not a valid token. It can be used in a macro argument as long as the macro argument is either stringified or not expanded.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Comments are processed at preprocessor phase.  You can do selective compilation (without regard to comments) with `#if` directives, as in:

```
#if 0
...  // this stuff will not be compiled
...
#endif // up to here.
```

that's all the magic you can do with the limited macro preprocessor available in C/C++.